# How to replace all occurrences of a string in a pandas data frame with NaN values?

Tags: python-3.x

I am just trying to figure out if there is a quick way to replace all occurrences of a string in a pandas data frame with NaN values. Like something that will check each value in the data frame and replace it with a `NaN` value if it's a `str` datatype.

I know we can do this for a certain string using `replace` method as:
`df.replace('Sample String', np.nan)`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

You can use this simple example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']})

df['col1'] = df['col1'].map(lambda x: np.nan if x in ['two', 'four'] else x)
```

df:

```
0      one
1      NaN
2    three
3      NaN
Name: col1, dtype: object
```

Comment: I am trying to do this: df.appy(lambda x: x if -isinstance(x, str) else np.nan)
But, I guess it fills the whole data frame with NaN values.

Comment: could you please give an example of what I am asking? I want to apply it to the whole data frame and get all the string values converted to NaN. Thanks

Comment: @UmarAftab please add example of your data in your question and example of what you need.